# interrogating table lock schemes in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sysobjects

Is there some means of querying the system tables to establish which tables are using what locking schemes? I took a look at the columns in **sysobjects** but nothing jumped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aargh, just being an idiot:

```
SELECT    name, lockscheme(name)
FROM      sysobjects
WHERE     type="U"
ORDER BY  name
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the syslockinfo and syslocks system tables
you can also run the sp_lock proc